# Why can't I Add 0 to CComSafeArray?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, atl, safearray

```
CComSafeArray<BYTE> arr;
arr.Add(0x00);
```

Error -> **C2668: 'ATL::CComSafeArray::Add' : ambiguous call to overloaded function**

I can add any value but can't add `0` , **why?**

btw currently I'm doing

```
const byte zero = 0x00;
arr.Add(zero);
```

but I don't understand the reason why I can't just add `0`

Comment: VS will tell you *all* the potentials that are making it ambiguous if you scroll down further. (where you will likely find a conflict with a pointer-to-something that is interpreting 0x0 as NULL, probably a LPSAFEARRAY, or some such; sry, don't have my toolchain handy). Try `static_cast<BYTE>(0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method adding an element is :

```
HRESULT Add(_In_ const T& t, _In_ BOOL bCopy = TRUE) // 0x00 as zero for t
```

that is, your argument is expected to be of type `const BYTE&`. There is however another `Add` method which can accept your zero argument:

```
HRESULT Add(_In_ const SAFEARRAY *psaSrc) // 0x00 as NULL for pasSrc
```

Hence the ambiguity and you are expected to resolve it by casting your argument appropriately:

```
CComSafeArray<BYTE> arr;
arr.Add((const BYTE&) 0x00);
```